# Setup wireless iPad - iTunes connection without connecting via USB first?

Tags: itunes, ipad

If a user plugs in an iPad into the USB port of a computer which is running iTunes, iTunes recognises iPad, and allows the user to manage apps or media files on the iPad from iTunes.

I know iTunes allows users to do that wirelessly (meaning that the iPad is not connected to the USB port of the computer running iTunes) if the iPad and the computer are connected to the same Wi-Fi network, but it seems that one must first connect the iPad to the computer at least once to make the iTunes recognise the iPad.

Is there any way to set up the wireless connection between an iPad and an iTunes (computer) without the initial USB connection?

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with the [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) portion of the [Help Centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) & help us to help you by providing as much detailed information as you can.

Comment: You should be able to setup your iPad to a wireless network the same way you setup any other device.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'USB connection' because the iPad doesn't have a USB port.  Can you please clarify what you're trying to do and what equipment you have?

Comment: I have added the details.

Comment: @fbara the iPad has either a 30 pin or Lightning to USB A connection

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I'm aware of the ports on an iPad.  My question was because the OP mentioned 'USB connection' and the iPad doesn't have a USB port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they have to the 'paired' via USB first.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.